Multiple PHP-FPM pools with Laravel site
I have a really simple Nginx config for a Laravel site.
I'd like to be able to use multiple PHP-FPM pools based on the URL passed.  For example testapp.net/api/... I would like to use the same Laravel site but a different FPM pool.
The pool is already setup on a different socket.
Everything I seem to try results in a 404 or the PHP script not executing.
Is this possible?

    root /var/www/prod/public;
    index index.php;

    location = /robots.txt {
        access_log off; log_not_found off;
    }
    location = /favicon.ico {
        access_log off; log_not_found off;
    }

    listen 443 ssl http2;

    server_name testapp.net;

    location ~* \.(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png|svg)(\?[0-9]+)?$ {
        expires 7d;
        break;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}


